# Alternative for datalist tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am preparing an entry screen in which the user has to enter 4 fields itemcode and description, unit of measurement, quantity, location and then press an add button.  When the user enters any text in itemcode and description field (a textbox) I want to display a list of codes and descriptions that are available for the text entered.

Currently, I am using a datalist but the performance is very slow in Mozilla Firefox as there are 47000+ items in the list. It's not at all opening in Internet Explorer and Chrome browser is getting hanged. Is there any alternative for this datalist in order to display the list of items for the user to select from?

Comment: fix spelling and grammar

Comment: Have a look at [awesomplete](https://github.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete). Hopefully it helps!